# How to set a "primary key" in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

This is the schema I plan to have for my message board app where users can create their own message boards:

```
{
    "boards" : {
        "jane-board" : {
            // meta information like who created this board
        },
        "john-board" : {
            // meta information like who created this board
        },
        ...
    },
    "jane-board" : {
        // data
    },
    "john-board" : {
        // data
    }
}
```

**What would be the rule to ensure that `"boards"` cannot contain two `"jane-board"`?**

I tried writing a rule but it fails:

```
{
    "rules" : {
        ".read" : true,
        "boards" : {
            ".write" : true,
            "$board_name" : {
                ".validate" : "!newData.parent().hasChild($board_name)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Answer below, based on an assumption of what you're trying to accomplish. If that is not your use-case, please edit your question to include a code sample of a write operation that is allowed and shouldn't be. You might also take that opportunity to change "it fails" into something more specific, such as "This code did A. I expected this code to do B".

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using the board's name as the key to store it under, there is already a guarantee that each board name can exist at most once.

It is not entire clear what you're trying to accomplish. But *if you are trying to prevent a board's data from being overwritten*, you can accomplish that with:

```
{
    "rules" : {
        ".read" : true,
        "boards" : {
            "$board_name" : {
                ".write" : "!data.parent().hasChild($board_name)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Changes for your rules:

- I removed the `".write": true` from `boards`. With that rule in place everyone can read *all* boards, since you [cannot take permissions away on a lower level](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-cascade).
- I changed the rule to a `".write"` rule, since it feels more like preventing a write than validating structure
- I check whether the new board already exists in the *current* data. You were checking in `newData`, but that doesn't make any sense: the new board will always exist in the new data.

Comment: Well, `board_name` is akin to a username. First come, first served. So, if Jane creates `jane_board`, any subsequent attempt by John to create `jane_board` should fail :)

Comment: The above rules will accomplish that. Note that they will also prevent Jane and John from making any edits to any board that they created.

Comment: A little digging, and I found that I can achieve just that with `curl -X PATCH` and passing it my whole board JSON object. or by using `set()` in JavaScript API in conjunction with `".validate" : "!data.parent().hasChild($board_name)"`